# Бродить: разные значения слова

Tags: омонимы

Бродить - ходить без определенной цели, медленно ходить. Отсюда бродяга - тот, кто постоянно куда-то идет, нигде надолго не останавливаясь.
Но почему при этом продукты тоже бродят? Википедия определяет брожение как процесс анаэробного расщепления органических веществ, преимущественно углеводов, происходящий под влиянием микроорганизмов или выделенных из них ферментов. Ничего общего с первым определением слова.
Но почему же бродит и человек, и, например, пиво?

Answer (score 2):

Вы никогда не наблюдали, как бродит в стеклянной банке хлебный квас?

На дне, где "обитают" дрожжи, образуются пузыри углекислого газа, которые, поднимаясь наверх, перемешивают все слои. Возникает медленное хаотичное движение, очень точно описываемое глаголом *бродить*. А перебродившее тесто может вообще "убежать" из квашни, переползти через край.

Кстати, от этого корня образовано английское bread "хлеб".

Comment: Считается, что  на значении современного английского слова bread сказалось скандинавское влияние, но оно связано с расширением этого значения "ломоть хлеба - хлеб". А у Вас есть информация о происхождении   др.-англ варианта "bread - ломоть хлеба"? Не очень понятна его  связь с глаголом "бродить", который в основном известен в славянских языках.

Comment: Вы читаете по-английски? Если да, то вот интересная статья http://deskarati.com/2013/08/04/the-etymology-of-the-word-bread/

В ней даётся версия о том, что bread происходит от brew "замешивать, сбраживать". Правда, далее более предпочтительной признана Ваша версия, но, если вспомнить, что по-немецки хлеб Brot...

А ещё там вскользь упомянуто, что до примерно 1200 года в древне -английском "хлеб" назывался hlaf! Наш родной хлебушек практически!!(Надеюсь, англоязычного автора никто не обвинит в "чудиновщине"?)
А по-фински "хлеб" leip. Финны не могут произнести в начале слова два согласных.